# Does "tre eble" mean "probable"?

Tags: meaning

I have found the structure *tre eble* meaning *probable* according to one definition of [Reta Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/probab.html). Is this use of *tre eble* correct? As I understand it now, *tre eble* means that something is very likely to be a possibility, not that the possibility is very likely to happen.

Answer (score 3):

My sense is that *tre eble* is an odd thing to say, and that *tre verŝajne* makes more sense. However, there are two references to it in Tekstaro (in the same work), and this link seems to suggest that it's OK.

http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kvantaj_vortoj/grado_kvanto.html

The argument seems to be that rejecting *tre eble* would require rejecting *kiel eble plej.*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to say that something is probable or likely to happen you should say *ĝi probable okazos* or *ĝi verŝajne okazos*.

*Ĝi eble okazos* means that it is *ebla, ne neebla*, not impossible: *ĝi povas okazi, tia okazo ne estas neebla, ĝia probablo ne egalas al nulo*.

*Tre eble* is just emphasizing that it is possible, not saying much about the likelihood of such a thing happening, just that the probability is definitely not equal to 0. But in everyday language you don't pay much attention to such logical thinking and it is quite possible (= *tre eble?*) that *tre eble* is used where *(most) likely* would be appropriate.